# How to run business logic on one computer of the local network and GUI on another?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml

I have a WPF application running on a computer which is connected to a local network and there is a special device connected to this computer which is controlled by the application. Is there any easy way to migrate the GUI (WPF XAML) to another computer connected to the same network so that the GUI and BL stay coupled?

I have been looking into WCF but there are quite some limitations which would make it time consuming to adapt WCF to my situation. WCF would work perfectly if it could handle both properties (not supported at all) and events in one ServiceContract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simple way to do that.
If your GUI and BL are running on different machines, then you have to implement special code to perform network communications between apps (i.e. GUI and BL are two different apps), and if GUI and BL are tightly coupled, it's almost impossible and pointless to do so (network-related code would contain service contracts tremendous in size and remoting would consume large amount of time, making UI interaction slow and painful) - it should be refactored.
 
    There is, however, a workaround for your problem - you can run your app on machine with both BL and GUI, then show that GUI on different machine: RemoteDesktop or RemoteApp (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) could help with that.

Comment: Network ops can be async, so they need to not make UI interaction painful . That said, I'm not sure this really answers the question (though you could argue it could solve his problem)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, I think,in general, async operations cannot save from problems with managing and synchronization of 'view state' between GUI and BL machines, if GUI and BL are tightly coupled. So, if refactoring isn't an option, than my answer should suffice, otherwise application should be reimplemented with client/server architecture

Comment: Sure, you have to have a decoupled architecture before *any* networking is possible. Of course, such an architecture is desirable anyways :). Never enough time to do it right, always enough time to do it over.

Comment: Obviously I made mistake when I chose WPF and basically I am thinking about redoing the thing with MVC but for the sake of time I'll stick with RemoteApps. So, thank you for the link.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev If you use MVVM with WPF (as you should) then the decoupled architecture should come *very* naturally.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Basically I am having MVVM with WPF and when I wrote "GUI and BL should stay coupled" I meant that GUI and VM should stay synchronized as in usual WPF MVVM. And when I mentioned events I meant that my VM is using other classes which are using events. But as far as I can see WCF does not allow to work with Properties which should be enough to say that WCF is not really applicable. Or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev It is 100% possible to use a WCF proxy as your model. You just have to get away from the idea of setting properties, and if you need events use a duplex WCF channel. Realize that you are actually talking to a *service* (which you are at that point) and design for that. The fact that you are using WPF is irrelevant at that point.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev The bindings should be to the *view model* which then talks to the WCF proxy (acting as the model). Bindings should not be affected. Consider coming to WPF chat to talk about this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Well, this is exatcly how I started adapting WCF to my case and that is why I came here to ask if there are other easier ways. As I wrote I can adapt my WPF/MVVM to work with WCF but that will take time. That being said.

Comment: @DmitryTimofeev Yes, it will take time. I don't deny this. However, as in my answer *any* solution will take time as you have to move to a server/client model. I'm glad you found a working solution :)

Answer (score 2):

An *easy* way? No.

You can, as you noted, use WCF. You could also use SignalR, a message bus, standard TCP sockets, or a number of other technologies.

**None** of these however will give you the absolute transparency you seem to desire. They all work off the concept that you are going to invoke a method on the server, and it may or may not return data. In the case of TCP, you send data and may get data back. You don't simply access/change a property or listen to an event (SignalR and WCF do support server->client invocation, which isn't *exactly* the same thing as an event, but it can work like one).

I think you need to look at implementing a standard client/server model, inconvenient as you may believe it to be.